# Can a RtAudio software record output audio of an Android OS Device, in an unrooted user case?

Tags: android, audio-recording, headphones, rtaudio

I liked to know if a RtAudio software can record output audio of an Android OS Device, in an unrooted user case.

RtAudio is available at:
http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtaudio/index.html .

By the way, I liked to know if a RtAudio software can record output audio from headphones, or from earphones, of an Android OS Device, when an unrooted user is using it.

I know that Android OS devices uses ALSA, or another well defined audio engine...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

RtAudio code can be written to use ALSA, PulseAudio or JACK on a Linux machine, and the answer may be different, depending on which audio engine you are using.

I'd say the easiest way to accomplish what wish to attempt is to use the JACK audio engine, as it was specifically designed to send audio data from one software application to another, so porting output from whatever is generating the audio and sending it to the input of a piece of recording software would be the most straightforward.  With bridges to JACK from both ALSA and PulseAudio for Linux, you should be able to record the output of any audio program.

Comment: Jason Harrer: I liked to know if I should be able to record the output of any audio program, with an unrooted user.

Comment: Again, the answer depends on which Audio System you're using under RtAudio for recording purposes. Without more information on your setup and which Audio System you're trying to use, I can't give you any more specific of an answer. If you want to give me more information (which Audio Systems are installed, how many sound cards are installed, which system/sound care you're trying to use within RtAudio, which system/sound card the source program is using, etc.), I can give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: Jason Harrer: I changed the question again. By the way, I am asking now about Android devices, with ALSA uses.